Principles and Techniques in Combinatorics Problem 84 part (i)

Given $r,n \in Z$ with $0\leq n \leq r$, the Stirling number S(r,n) of the second kind is defined as the number of ways of distributing $r$ distinct objects into $n$ identical boxes such that no box is empty. Show that $$S(r,2) = 2^{r-1} - 1$$

Please give me a hint for this problem

Since the boxes are otherwise indistinguishable, and the "first" object has to go in some box... let us simply distinguish the boxes in relation to whichever box the "first" object happens to end up in.  Now, for all objects other than the first... pick which box they go in.  The same box as the first, or the other box.

First, make sure you understand the given definition of $S(r,n)$ so that you know what $S(r,2)$ means. Can you write out all the object/box configurations to confirm the value of $S(4,2)$, for example?

Assume the boxes aren't identical. Each of the $r$ objects has $2$ "choices". It either goes to box $1,$ or it goes to box $2.$ This gives $2^r$ ways. But, we are overcounting by $2$ cases, the case where every object goes to box $1,$ and the case where every object goes to box $2.$ So, for now, the count is $2^r-2.$ But, we need to divide out by $2$ now, since the boxes are identical. Hence, $S(r,2)=2^{r-1}-1.$
